# How to reduce the length of title in Blogger?

Tags: post, title, blogger, blogspot

Aloha guys, I'm new here. I really want to reduce the length of the title (reduce the number of words) so that it blends in well with the theme. My website's default view is Grid View, and I want the titles to be changed to "..." when it overflows the limit and the text comes on image. I hope you get what I mean. The text is getting cut away... I seriously need help!

The website is

http://www.apps-mania.com/

If anyone is ready to help, please poke me up :) 
Cheers,
Ayush

Answer (score 1):

The CSS you are looking for is

```
 text-overflow:ellipsis
```

http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html